# What is the justfication for splitting up statements and quantifiers?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

To explain the title, in proving $X \times Y = \emptyset \iff X = \emptyset \vee Y = \emptyset$, we have the following

\begin{align*}
X \times Y = \emptyset &\iff \forall x \forall y  \left((x,y) \notin X \times Y\right)\\
&\iff \forall x \forall y  \left(x \notin X \vee y \notin Y\right) \\
&\iff \forall x (x \notin X) \vee \forall y (y \notin Y) \\
&\iff X = \emptyset \vee Y = \emptyset ,
\end{align*}

and in particular going from the second to the third line, we can (?) split up the statement $(x \notin X \vee y \notin Y)$ and quantifiers $\forall x \forall y$ into two separate statements each with its own quantifier. **I'm not sure why this is true.** It seems obvious that this is true, but is there a proof, or is it axiomatic? Or is it not true at all?

Thanks in advance - recently deleted a completely wrong proof of this statement so hopefully this one is at least correct

Comment: If you are writing or reading predicate logic proofs, how is it you haven't found out what proof rules, rule schemas & identities you are allowed to use/expect? (Rhetorical.)

Comment: You said "rhetorical", but I actually answered that question in the reply to Lee's answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could insert the following intermediate steps:
\begin{align*}
\forall x \forall y  \left(x \notin X \vee y \notin Y\right) 
& \iff \forall x\bigl( \forall y (x \notin X \vee y \notin Y) \bigr) \\
& \iff \forall x\bigl(x \notin X \vee \forall y (y \notin Y)\bigr)
\\
& \iff \bigl(\forall x (x \notin X)\bigr) \vee \bigl(\forall y (y \notin Y) \bigr)
\end{align*}
The second and third steps are applications of one of the [Laws of Quantifier Movement](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1992456) in predicate logic, which says that if the free variable $x$ does not occur in the statement $P$ then you can move a universal $x$ quantifier into an "or" statement that involves $P$, in the following manner:
$$\forall x (P \vee Q(x)) \iff P \vee (\forall x Q(x))
$$
I think of this as an "infinite" version of de Moivre's Theorem: if $x_1,x_2,...$ is a "list" of the values of $x$ then
$$(P \vee Q(x_1)) \wedge (P \vee Q(x_2)) \wedge \cdots \iff P \vee (Q(x_1) \wedge Q(x_2) \wedge \cdots)
$$

Comment: Thanks Lee. I'm reading an analysis book which is attempting to touch on proving statements rigorously using first order logic in the first chapter, but they don't mention this at all. Perhaps the author has tried to do too much.

Comment: What I said about deMoivre's Theorem is a little careless, the implication is only one way. But I don't have time to fix it right now.

Comment: cheers for the heads up

Comment: Okay, fixed now.

Comment: By the way, regarding the author doing "too much", even a first analysis course might assume, as a prerequisite, some knowledge of predicate calculus including laws of quantifiers. Books at that level sometimes have a "chapter zero" to bring a student up to speed on set theory and maybe also on predicate logic, but not always.